# Rebinding knockout datatable on button click

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, knapsack-problem

I am displaying data table on button click created using knockout it works fine on first click  pop up gets opened and data table works fine 
when i close this popup and again open it. It shows messay data i tried using ko.cleannode and then again apply binding but with no result.
Here is my html code

```
 <div id="res_edit" class="modal hide" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"    aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" id="res_close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
                <h3 id="myModalLabel">Select Company</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="modal_Container" >
                <table >
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input data-bind="value: nameSearch, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input data-bind="value: lastNameSearch, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="grid-row-align: start">
                        <td>
                            <button data-bind="click:filter">Search</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <table id="modal_table" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th  data-bind="click:sortTable" orderProp ="firstName">Company
                                <span>
                <i data-bind="attr: { class: iconType }"></i>
            </span>
                            </th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Logo</th>

                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="1">
                                <button data-bind="click: previousSlot, enable: slot() >0" class="btn"><i class="icon-step-backward"></i></button>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <label data-bind="foreach: new Array(pages())">
                                    <a data-bind="text: (parseInt($parent.span()) + $index()+1), id: $index()+1, click: $parent.navigatePage"></a>
                                </label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <button data-bind="click: nextSlot, enable: hasNextRecords()" class="btn"><i class="icon-step-forward"></i></button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody data-bind="template:{name:templateToUse, foreach: currentPage } " id="tblMain">
                    </tbody>
                    <tfoot>

                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <button data-bind="click: previousSlot, enable: slot() >0 " class="btn"><i class="icon-step-backward"></i></button>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <label data-bind="foreach: new Array(pages())">
                                    <a data-bind="text: (parseInt($parent.span())+ $index()+1), id: $index()+1, click: $parent.navigatePage"></a>
                                </label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <button data-bind="click: nextSlot,enable: hasNextRecords()" class="btn"><i class="icon-step-forward"></i></button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Number of items per page:
            <select id="pageSizeSelector" data-bind="value: pageSize">
                <option value="10">10</option>
                <option value="20">25</option>
                <option value="30">50</option>
                <option value="100">100</option>
            </select>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tfoot>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
            </div>
        </div>
```

My js code is 
       $('.res_edit').click(function () {
        GetRecordsForDataTable(columnslist, vm);
        $('#res_edit').show();

```
  });


  $('#res_close').click(function () {
    $('#res_edit').hide();
  });


   function GetRecordsForDataTable(columnslist, vm) {
     var request = { recordsLength: 100 };
    var element = $("#modal_Container")[0];
   ko.cleanNode(element);
    $.ajax({
    url: "../DashBoard/GetRecords",
    type: "GET",
    data: request
 }).done(function (response) {
    if (vm.currentList().length > 0) {
        vm.currentList([]);
        ko.mapping.fromJS(response, viewModel);
        ko.cleanNode(window.document.getElementById("#res_edit"));
        ko.applyBindings(vm, window.document.getElementById("#res_edit"));
    }
    else {
        ko.applyBindings(vm, window.document.getElementById("#res_edit"));
        vm.currentList(response);
    }

   }).fail(function (de) {
    alert("Sorry. Server unavailable. ");
  });
  }
```

Comment: In your `.done` function, try changing this line `ko.mapping.fromJS(response, viewModel);` to this `ko.mapping.fromJS(response, {}, viewModel);` and remove the the other lines you have in the `.done` function. If you are updating the view model (refreshing view model data with data from server), then the bindings are already applied and you just need to use the `ko.mapping` to update the data

Comment: Some unsolicited advice... rather than using jQuery to handle the click/show/hide events, use knockout bindings. I doubt it is related to this particular problem, but I think it will cause less headaches in the long run. 
All of the click events and show/hide events in your example can be handle with 'click' and 'visible' bindings, respectively

Comment: you're initially binding to #res_edit but attempting to 'cleanNode' #modal_Container...

Comment: Thanks all for responding but i am still facing the same issue

Comment: Hey thanks rwish45 your comments improved it and finally beauXjames because of you i noticed my silly mistake thanks both of you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `.done` function, try changing this line `ko.mapping.fromJS(response, viewModel);` to this `ko.mapping.fromJS(response, {}, viewModel);` And remove the the other lines you have in the `.done` function.

If you are updating the view model (refreshing view model data with data from server), then the bindings are already applied and you just need to use the `ko.mapping` to update the data – [rwisch45](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20549973/rebinding-knockout-datatable-on-button-click#comment30735105_20549973)

You're initially binding to `#res_edit` but attempting to `'cleanNode' #modal_Container`... – [beauXjames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20549973/rebinding-knockout-datatable-on-button-click#comment30736654_20549973)